Why is np.sort() with order slow on multi dtype arrays? (sorting by unsigned integer ID)
Working with embedded software, I'm using numpy arrays with specified datatypes to save memory and other reasons. I'm using version '1.23.4' and Python 3.10.0, but this seems to be an issue with latest versions too. In a task I noticed that sorting this array with np.sort(..., order='id')seems to be very slow. This comes as a surprise, as if we just sort the ID column separately with np.sort it is handled fastly, and no other column is relevant for the sorting.
A similar small example:
dtypes = [('x', 'u1'), ('id', '<u8')]
x_values = [n % 2 for n in range(5000000)]
ids = list(range(5000000, 0, -1))
x = np.array(list(zip(x_values, ids)), dtype=dtypes)

Now, if I run np.sort(x, order='id'), it takes on my machine around 15-20 seconds. Compared to np.sort(x['id']) which runs in 1/100th of the time, it seems unreasonably slow. This suggests workarounds to not sort the complete array directly.
What increases this complexity when using a multi datatype array?

According to the documentation, unspecified fields will still be used, so those two are not a fair comparison. In fact, if we try it with random data, the two will be in a different order. However, I have confirmed that x[np.lexsort([x[name] for name in x.dtype.names])] (which gives the same result as np.sort(x, order='id')) is still several times faster. So the question should remain the same.

Not a c expert (any expert feel free to correct), but looking in methods.c at array_sort it looks like if you have an order parameter it's making a copy instead of sorting in-place.  That shouldn't increase the time by that much though.

Can you use idx=np.argsort((x['id']) to get the order?  And then x[idx].
